# Importing a Table to R with text that includes "#" characters

Tags: r

I am importing a table into R using the following method:

```
mydata <- read.table("C:/textfile.txt", sep="\t", header=FALSE)
```

My text file contains fields that use the `#` character, everything following `#` does not get imported. How can I force R to include this data?

```
# Leg

Buyer

1

Call

Qty (MMBTU ) 1,000,000

2

Clearing # 123456789
```

[Link to the text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vshxk3yy8f3yw3j/textfile.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the argument `comment.char = ""`:

```
mydata <- read.table("C:/textfile.txt", sep = "\t", header = FALSE, comment.char = "")
```

The default is `comment.char = "#"`, therefore everything following `#` is ignored.